# How to exclude documents based on standard format name when sending e-mails?

Tags: vba, outlook

We have a macro that sends e-mails of documents in a certain directory. We want to exclude documents whose file names begin with "AUT_XXXXXX" ETA: the Xs can be a string of letters and numbers that vary.

```vb
Sub SendScannedDocstoWellsFargo()
    Dim Filename As Variant
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim strDirectory As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Filename = Dir("\\kwa-file01\ClientFiles\Wells Fargo III\_Scanned_Documents\Pending Uploads\")
    
    strDirectory = "\\kwa-file01\ClientFiles\Wells Fargo III\_Scanned_Documents\Pending Uploads\"
    
    While Filename <> ""
        'Comment out when completed
        'Debug.Print Filename
        'Set the filename to the next file
        Filename = Dir
        'Create a path for the item
        strPath = strDirectory & Filename
        If strPath = strDirectory Then GoTo StopThisNow
        
        'Create a mail item
        Set olNewEmail = olApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
        With olNewEmail
            .To = "ccslegaldocuments@wellsfargo.com"
            .Subject = Filename
            .Attachments.Add (strPath)
            .Send
        End With
        
        FSO.DeleteFile strPath, True
        
        Set olNewEmail = Nothing
StopThisNow:
    Wend
    
    Set olApp = Nothing
    Set olNewEmail = Nothing
    strDirectory = ""
    Filename = ""
    strPath = ""
End Sub
```

I've seen posts showing how to exclude PDFs.

Comment: Instead of adding the whole folder `.Attachments.Add (strPath)` loop through the files in that folder, test each file if it begins with `AUT_XXXXXX.` and if not add this file. Give it a try your self and then [edit] and show what you have tried ([No attempt was made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try.

Read the code's comments and adjust it to fit your needs.

EDIT: Changed to Like statement with wildcards

```
Public Sub SendScannedDocstoWellsFargo()
    
    ' Define the folder path
    Dim folderPath As String
    folderPath = "C:\Temp\" ' "\\kwa-file01\ClientFiles\Wells Fargo III\_Scanned_Documents\Pending Uploads\"
    
    ' Define the file name string to exclude
    Dim stringExclude As String
    stringExclude = "AUT_??????"
    
    ' Set a referece to the FSO object
    Dim FSO As FileSystemObject
    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    ' Set a reference to Outlook application
    Dim outlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Set outlookApp = Outlook.Application
    
    ' Get files in folder
    Dim fileName As String
    fileName = Dir(folderPath)
    
    ' Loop through files
    Do While fileName <> ""
    
        If Not Left(fileName, Len(stringExclude)) Like stringExclude Then
            
            ' Build the file path
            Dim filePath As String
            filePath = folderPath & fileName
            
            ' Send the email by calling a procedure
            sendEmail outlookApp, filePath, fileName
            
            ' Delete the file
            FSO.DeleteFile filePath, True
        
        End If
        
        ' Call next file
        fileName = Dir
    
    Loop
    
    ' Clean up outlook reference
    Set outlookApp = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub sendEmail(ByVal outlookApp As Outlook.Application, ByVal filePath As String, ByVal fileName As String)

    Dim olNewEmail As Outlook.MailItem
    
    'Create a mail item
    Set olNewEmail = outlookApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With olNewEmail
        .To = "ccslegaldocuments@wellsfargo.com"
        .Subject = fileName
        .Attachments.Add filePath
        .Send
    End With
    
    Set olNewEmail = Nothing
    
End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: I apologize, I should have clarified that the Xs can be a string of letters and numbers that vary.

Comment: @CandiceHoward pls see my edit and try the new code